# Resolver variables booleanas sin usar condicionales ni librerías EN JAVA

Tags: java, funciones, programación-bajo-nivel

buenas tardes. Estamos haciendo nuestra primera practica de programación y no sabemos como resolver uno de los ejercicios sin usar condicionales ni librerías. Nos vendría muy bien la ayuda, gracias.

EJERCICIO: Crea una función la cual recibe un número entero. Si el entero es positivo que devuelva un 1, si es negativo que devuelva -1 y si recibe un 0 que devuelva un 0

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Debes demostrar algo de lo que intentaron hasta ahora. no puedes usar if ni nada parecido?

Answer (score 1):

No recuerdo bien como crear los metodos en java porque llevo años sin programar en java pero seria algo asi

```
public int isPositiveOrNot(int num){
   int result=compare(num,0);
    return result;
  }
```

La funcion compare te devuelve 0 si es igual, negativo o positivo dependiendo, tambien mirate `compareTo`  en la api de java, espero te ayude

Answer (score 1):

No sé si esto se considera una condición:

```
int simbolo(int num) {
  return num ==0 ? 0: num>0? 1:-1;
}
```

Otra opción sería:

```
int simbolo(Integer num) {
  return num.compareTo(0);
}
```

Comment: Creo que la primera opción sigue siendo una condición, sólo que en lambda, pero tu segunda opción es la correcta ;)

Comment: Wow, muchisimas gracias!, ambas son correctas según nuestra profesora!

Answer (score 0):

public boolean numeroEntero(Integer num){
        if(num>0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

Comment: el ejercicio no nos permite usar condicions como if ni else, pero muchas gracias